# Does Weapon Finesse affect Combat Maneuvers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, combat-maneuver

If a character has the [Weapon Finesse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-finesse-combat-final/) feat, and is wielding an appropriate weapon, is the Combat Maneuver bonus changed to include the Dex bonus, or not? How about for Combat Maneuver Defense - would you include the Dex bonus twice, or does it stay unchanged?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes, but only with disarm, sunder, and trip attempts.**

Having the Weapon Finesse feat allows you to substitute your Dexterity modifier to your Strength modifier when determining the combat maneuver checks made with an applicable weapon (as stated in [an answer about Weapon Finesse](http://paizo.com/products/btpy88yj/faq?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Core-Rulebook#v5748eaic9ojt) on the official FAQs). Remember to also apply the armor check penalty of your shield, if any.

If you like a more universal approach you could take the [Agile Maneuvers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/agile-maneuvers-combat) feat (which substitutes your Dexterity modifier to your Strength modifier when computing your CMB with **all** maneuvers (from bull rush to trip).

Neither Weapon Finesse, nor Agile Maneuvers affect your CMD.